# Updating Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

Hi how do I update facebook sdk for iOS? Do I just simply delete the whole folder in Document or is it okay to overwrite it? I currently have 3.6 and the latest version is 3.8. Do I have to uninstall the old one to install the latest update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you'd just delete the folder and then add the new folder, keeping in mind that you'll have to link the SDK library within your Xcode project again.  I'd really recommend using a dependency manager like [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) to simplify this situation in the future.

Also, make sure you read the official upgrade documents:

3.6 to 3.7: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-from-3.6-to-3.7/

3.7 to 3.8: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-from-3.7-to-3.8/

Comment: Thanks. I think installing cocoapods will just complicate the matter so I'll just delete 3.6 and install 3.8.